# Bluetooth LE: Send data from iOS got cuts short

Tags: swift3, bluetooth-lowenergy, thermal-printer

If this has been asked before, I apologize.
I send a long string that contains about length of 750 bytes from iOS device to a bluetooth thermal printer.  However, when the string is printed out, the printer only prints out partial of the context which is about 160 bytes in CChar.  I am a bit confused why this happens, can any one care to explain about this?

code:

```
let cfEnc = CFStringEncodings.GB_18030_2000
let enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(cfEnc.rawValue))

let ccc = "The franchise began in 1977 with the release of the film Star Wars 
    (subtitled Episode IV: A New Hope in 1981[2][3]), which became a worldwide pop 
    culture phenomenon. It was followed by the successful sequels The Empire 
    Strikes Back (1980) and Return of the Jedi (1983); these three films constitute 
    the original Star Wars trilogy. A prequel trilogy was released between 1999 and 
    2005, which received mixed reactions. A sequel trilogy began in 2015 with the 
    release of Star Wars: The Force Awakens. All seven films were nominated for 
    Academy Awards (with wins going to the first two films) and have been 
    commercial successes, with a combined box office revenue of $7.471 billion,[4] 
    making Star Wars the third highest-grossing film series.[5] Spin-off films 
    include Star Wars: The Clone Wars (2008) and Rogue One (2016), which is the 
    first in an upcoming series of anthology films.\n\nThe series has spawned an 
    extensive media franchise—the Star Wars expanded universe—including books, 
    television series, computer and video games, and comic books, resulting in 
    significant development of the series's fictional universe. Star Wars also 
    holds a Guinness World Records title for the \"Most successful film 
    merchandising franchise. In 2015, the total value of the Star Wars franchise 
    was estimated at USD $41.9 billion,[6] making Star Wars the second highest-
    grossing media franchise of all time.\n\nIn 2012, The Walt Disney Company 
    acquired Lucasfilm for $4.06 billion and earned the distribution rights to all 
    subsequent Star Wars films, beginning with the release of The Force Awakens in 
    2015.[7] The former distributor, 20th Century Fox, retains the physical 
    distribution rights to the first two Star Wars trilogies, owning permanent 
    rights for the original 1977 film and holding the rights to Episodes I–III, V, 
    and VI until May 2020.[8][9] Walt Disney Studios owns digital distribution 
    rights to all the Star Wars films, excluding A New Hope."
print(ccc.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: enc))) //count number is 164           

if let data = ccc.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: enc)) {
    self.writeValue(data)
}
```

in writeValue function

```
private func writeValue(_ data: Data!) {
    self.printerPeripheral?.writeValue(data, for: self.writeCharacteristic, type: .withResponse)
    print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    print(self.writeCharacteristic.uuid.uuidString)
    print("sending number of byte to BLE：\(data!)") // I get 748 as return
    print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
}
```

Do I have to chop string in order to have it work?

[image: the print out]

Comment: What is the model of the printer? I'm having the same problem on Android, it only writes 20 characters in Low Energy. Already in the classic bluetooth works correctly.

Comment: I actually found the problem.
It was caused because the length is too long, so I ended up chop the long text and sent bit by bit